# Allow admin role to view certain pages in Parse

Tags: admin, parse-platform

So as of right now I just have a page that I use locally to change objects. How can I go about creating a page that is only visible to the admin user. Using roles you can restrict access to certain objects but Im not sure the best way to include a page in your application that is only visible to certain users. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an AccessRole (or similar) class that you can use for this, then show or hide the link/button (from menu or whatever) to open that page. Users who are not members of the Admin role does not see the button/link/menu option.

In the AccessRole class, you have a "users" column where you store an array of users that are members of the role, and a "name" column for the role name (Admin, Editor, Reader etc).

When your application starts, you check if the user is a member of the Admin role (which should be temporarily stored locally).

Comment: Thanks for the response. That seems like a nice solution. Is there any security problems to think about here? I assume as long as you have a good system for distinguishing roles it shouldnt be a problem?

Comment: Well, for security in modifying objects you should rely on ordinary roles to restrict access to those objects. That is a separate concern. If you have that set up correctly, the new AccessRole will not interfere with that